# Complex SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I want a SimpleDateFormat that will allow me to show dates in this way:

```
Lunes, 03/09/2012 a las 9:59
```

(Lunes means Monday in spanish)

Is there a string I can use to build such a SimpleDateFormat or will I have to manipulate the Date manually?

Comment: It is possible using SimpleDateFormat. Read the documentation, everything is in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("es", "ES");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy 'a las' HH:mm", locale);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Result:

lunes, 03/09/2012 a las 10:26

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 Locale locale = new Locale("es", "ES");
 Log.i("Current Date :: ",getCurrentDate("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy 'a las' hh:mm",locale));

public static String getCurrentDate(String dateFormat,Locale locale)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat,locale);
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}

Current Date :: lunes, 03/09/2012 a las 01:52
```